# Trying to use a global 2D array between 2 class files in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, global-variables

So I'm in the process of writing a game in C++ and there comes a situation where I need to share a 2D array globally between multiple class files. Here is a simpler version of my code:

//First file that creates and writes the values for railsmentity[7][100]

```
#include "weaponfire.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sdtlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

//Ship common variables
extern int shipgun;
extern int shipgunammo;
extern double shippower;

//Gun variables
extern int railsm[];
/*
//Projectile common variables
extern double gunx;
extern double guny;
extern double gunz;
extern double gunpitch;
extern double gunyaw;
extern double gunspeed;
extern double gunspeedmax;
*/
//Ship navigation variables
extern double x;
extern double y;
extern double z;
extern double pitch;
extern double yaw;
extern double truespeed;

//Entity variables
int extern railsmentitycount;
int railsmentity[7][100];//[0]existance, [1]x, [2]y, [3]z, [4]pitch, [5]yaw, [6]truespeed, [7]maxspeed
int railsmentitycountcurrent = 0;

extern bool space;
int looptemp = 0;

weaponfire::weaponfire()
{
    if(space == true){
        if(shipgun == 0){//No weapon
            printf("No weapon equipped!\n");
        }

        if(shipgun == 1){//railsm
            if(shipgunammo > 0 && shippower >= railsm[7]){//Check ammo and power
                shipgunammo--;//Decrease ammo
                shippower = shippower - railsm[7];//Drain power

                //Find a valid storage position
                while(looptemp <= 100){//If you are within the variable list bounds
                    if(railsmentity[0][looptemp] == 0){//If the entity slot is available
//                        railsmentitycountcurrent = railsmentitycount;
                        looptemp = 0;
                    }
                    else{//If entity slot is not available
                        if(looptemp > 100){
                            printf("Error\n");
                        }
                        looptemp++;
                    }
                }

                //railsm local initial entity raycast
                railsmentity[0][railsmentitycountcurrent] = 1;
                railsmentity[1][railsmentitycountcurrent] = x;
                railsmentity[2][railsmentitycountcurrent] = y;
                railsmentity[3][railsmentitycountcurrent] = z;
                railsmentity[4][railsmentitycountcurrent] = pitch;
                railsmentity[5][railsmentitycountcurrent] = yaw;
                railsmentity[6][railsmentitycountcurrent] = truespeed;
            }
        }
    }
}

weaponfire::~weaponfire()
{
    //dtor
}
```

//This other class file then, for current simplicity, displays a specific //value of the railsmentity array

```
#include "railsmentity.h"
#include "weaponfire.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

extern int railsmentity[7][100];//[0]existance, [1]x, [2]y, [3]z, [4]pitch, [5]yaw, [6]truespeed, [7]maxspeed

railsmentity::railsmentity()
{
    printf("%d\n", railsmentity[1][1]);
}

railsmentity::~railsmentity()
{
    //dtor
}
```

But I get errors on the second program that states *In constructor 'railsmentity::railsmentity()'* and a second error says *error: expected primary-expression before '[' token* in reference to the line *printf("%d\n", railsmentity[1][1]);*

So what do I need to do to make this variable accessible?

Comment: Short hint: don't use 2D arrays, only 1D arrays (and often `std::vector`-s)

Comment: Why not creating a struct `Railsmentity` for `[0]existance, [1]x, [2]y, [3]z, [4]pitch, [5]yaw, [6]truespeed, [7]maxspeed` ? And then just have `std::vector<Railsmentity> Railsmentity;`

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable and a class with the same name, `railsmentity`. This doesn't work in C++, you need to rename one of them to something else.

Comment: Thank you lonut! I never noticed that, code now compiles and runs with the variable name change.